# How to set-up NodeJs client and server using docker-compose?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I have the following `node.js` scripts:

**client.js**

```
const net = require('net');
const client = new net.Socket();

client.connect(9233, 'server', (error) => {
    console.log('Connected to packet feed');
});

client.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log(err);
})
```

**server.js**

```
const net = require('net');

const server = net.createServer((socket) => {
});

server.listen(9233, 'localhost');
```

And the following `docker-compose.yaml`

```
version: '3'
services:
  server:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app
    command: node server.js
    ports:
      - "9233:9233"
  client:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app
    environment:
    command: node clients.js
    links:
      - server
    depends_on:
      - server
```

If I run `node server.js` and `node client.js` on my machine, they connect to each other sucessfully.

But if I run `docker-compose up`, I'll get the following error:

```
client_1       | Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.26.0.2:9233
client_1       |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1056:14) {
client_1       |   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
client_1       |   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
client_1       |   syscall: 'connect',
client_1       |   address: '172.26.0.2',
client_1       |   port: 9233
client_1       | }
```

What am I doing wrong? 
I've tried everything I could, including `docker-compose run --service-ports` instead of `docker-compose up`.

Comment: Have you tried using a different port for your local connection to the instance? try changing the left hand port to something surely unused, like 15000 and running it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `server.listen()` call, you need to specify the magic IPv4 "everywhere" address 0.0.0.0.  If you specify `localhost` there, it will be unreachable from outside the container.  (It will only accept connections coming from the container's `localhost`, and each container has its own `localhost`.)